# Fill Color to rotator in transformer konva.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I want my rotator of transformer to have icon, but first I add fill to learn.

```
  var rot = transformer.findOne('.rotater');
  console.log(rot); //Works fine
  rot.fill('orange'); //Not working. no need for fill-priority  
  layer.batchDraw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`konva@7.0.4` doesn't have API to customize specific anchors of a `Konva.Transformer`.

Your code doesn't work, because `Konva.Transfomer` may reset its style at any point of time with internal `tr.update()` function.

As a workaround, you can overwrite `update` method and add your own styles there:

```js
const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  nodes: [shape]
})

tr.update = function() {
  Konva.Transformer.prototype.update.call(tr);
  var rot = this.findOne('.rotater');
  rot.fill('orange');
}

tr.forceUpdate();

layer.add(tr);
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/lumisacayo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Useful to know. Also, can you provide a sample for setting a left-right arrow on the rotator ? The idea being to show the unfamiliar user that they can move the rotator to affect the shape. The transformer + rotator is a UX pattern that many understand but its not universal.

Comment: Do you mean a left-right arrow icon? If so, I think the simplest solution will be just setting fillPattern with icon image of the anchor rectangle.

Comment: @lavrton Doing it, will add the jsbin link

Comment: Just something to give an uninformed user the idea that something good will happen if the rotator gets dragged.